# Antiderivative that is non-differentiable at endpoints?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is there a function $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$, and a function $F$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, with $F’(x) = f(x)$ on $(a,b)$, but $F$ is not differentiable at one (or both) of $a$ or $b$? That is, can $F$ be not left-differentiable at $b$ or not right-differentiable at $a$?

And, if $F$ happens to be differentiable at an endpoint: must $F' = f$ at the endpoint as well?

Comment: This is forbidden by fundamental theorem of calculus. More generally let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and $F(x) =\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ and let $c\in[a, b] $ such that one sided limit of $f$ at $c$ is $L$. Then $F$ has same sided derivative at $c$ and the value of this derivative is $L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible.

Providing the hypothesis, $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \ dx$ for $x \in (a,b)$. Now, if you suppose that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, you also get that $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \ dx$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. And then $F$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ too.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible.

**Lemma**: Let $f, g$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, with $f’(x) = g’(x)$ for $x \in (a,b)$. Then there is a constant $C$ such that $f(x) = g(x) + C$ for $x \in [a,b]$.

**Proof**: Put $h := f - g$. Since $h' = f’ - g’ = 0$ on $(a,b)$, $h$ is constant here, say $h = C$ on $(a,b)$. By continuity, $h(a) = h(b) = C$ also. So $h = C$ on $[a,b]$. $\square$

Let $G(x) := \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ on $[a,b]$, so (by the fundamental theorem) $G’ = f$ on $[a,b]$. By the Lemma, $F = G + C$ on $[a,b]$. Hence $F' = G' = f$ on $[a,b]$.